# Cannot show chart by trigger

Tags: android, charts

ASK.
I use this **com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v2.2.4** for showing chart, I have an activity for show it I stright call the function in OnCreat, and the chart is show.
but when the function script triggered by button to call the function it doesn't show

can anyone help me?

this is my function script

```
protected void bar(){
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"masuk",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    ArrayList<BarEntry> entries = new ArrayList<>();
    entries.add(new BarEntry(10, 0));
    entries.add(new BarEntry(3, 1));
    entries.add(new BarEntry(6, 2));
    entries.add(new BarEntry(10, 3));
    entries.add(new BarEntry(3, 4));
    entries.add(new BarEntry(6, 5));

    entries.add(new BarEntry(10,6));
    entries.add(new BarEntry(3, 7));
    entries.add(new BarEntry(6, 8));
    BarDataSet datasets = new BarDataSet(entries, null);

    ArrayList<String> labels1 = new ArrayList<String>();
    labels1.add("asd");
    labels1.add("asd");
    labels1.add("dsa");
    labels1.add("asd");
    labels1.add("asd");
    labels1.add("dsa");
    labels1.add("asd");
    labels1.add("qwe");
    labels1.add("asd");

    BarData datas = new BarData(labels1,datasets);
    datasets.setColors(ColorTemplate.COLORFUL_COLORS);
    barChart.setData(datas);
    barChart.setScaleEnabled(true);
    barChart.setDragEnabled(true);
    barChart.setTouchEnabled(true);
}
```

Comment: show us how the function script triggered by button to call the function

Comment: `Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnshow);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               bar();
            }
        });`

Comment: I alse have declare barChart like `barChart = (BarChart) findViewById(R.id.Bar);`